# Use user-defined variable in Create Table statement to specify varchar length

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
SET @foo_width = 10;

CREATE TABLE test_table (
  foo varchar(@foo_width)
);
```

---

The exact problem is that I will need the same varchar-width for different columns across different tables. So, thought it'd be better if it could be stored in a variable.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea.  You can't do it directly, and MySQL doesn't support user-defined types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly, and MySQL doesn't support user-defined types.

At best, you can use **PREPARED STATEMENT** like this or you generate your query in your application.

```
SET @foo_width = 10;

SELECT CONCAT("CREATE TABLE test_table (
  foo varchar(",@foo_width,")
);") INTO @myquery;

select @myquery; -- only for test

PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```